# Are Changes Made to the CRM Unsecure Configuration Settings of a Plugin Instantaneous

Tags: dynamics-crm-online, dynamics-crm-2015

If I have some configuration changes in the Unsecure (does it matter?) Configuration Settings, and I make a change, will that force all instances of the plugin to get the newest settings, or does it take a while for the configuration settings to propagate?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The change does have to propagate to each front end web server, so I have definitely seen very short delays before, but I'm talking seconds.  The vast majority of the time, as soon as I hit Update Step and then initiate whatever action in the UI, I can see that the plugin ran with the updated configuration value.

I'm less sure about delays when it comes to plugins running in the async service.  Meaning, if 30 async plugins/wfs are queued up, you make your config change, I'm not sure if those queued up async jobs will use the new value or the old.

One easy way to investigate this would be for your plugin to write to the trace log and then set the trace log level in system settings to all.  Plugin-trace log records show what configuration values the plugin ran with.

Comment: I'm attempting to think about caching in CRM online.  In online, each plugin registration step is in it's own domain... (joy) which really limits caching, but the problem really is, how to I force the cache to be cleared.  I'm thinking that updating the Configuration Setting will force new instances of the plugin (since the settings are passed in via the constructor), effectively clearing my cache. Does that sound plausible?

Comment: I was going to suggest creating a special entity with plugin (and say a toolbar button) just for the purposes of clearing the cache, but that would only affect the cache of whatever front end server your request hits.  So yeah, your idea of updating configuration is a good one as that would very likely reinstantiate the plugin on each server.  On a related note, I recently discovered and used MemoryCache + Lazy for plugin caching with success (I used a static value for expiration because it was fine for my needs). http://blog.falafel.com/working-system-runtime-caching-memorycache/

Comment: Yes, I've been using memory cache for a couple years now.  Used to use it in On Prem, non-sandboxed plugins all share the same app pool.  Was trying to figure out how to handle this for CRM Online.